# Python plotting package with actual Python API

Tags: python, programming, plotting

Matplotlib is the number one plotting package for Python. But it has an extremely non-pythonic API (directly cloned it seems from Matlab). It's unnecessarily complicated, very counter-intuitive and it's not going to change soon (or ever).

So I'm looking for a plotting package with similar capabilities and that actually has a pythonic API. The only one I could find so far is Plotly, but it's exclusively online-based and I need to be able to do things offline so that's not good.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Check here for more plotting options:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting

I began using matplotlib about 60 days ago. I've really come to like it and suggest you give it another chance.  Its very well documented, extremely versatile, and supported by many stack overflow users.

Here's a quick sample of what I've accomplished in a few hours a day:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not just starting to with matplotlib, I've been doing for at least 4 years. It's just that more and more I realize that it's unnecessarily complicated. But I agree that it's extremely versatile. Don't agree it's well-documented though. Nice wiki page btw.